# How to only select cell for row in rowcallback function datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable, callback, datatables-1.10

```
rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
                              var occp = parseFloat(data[4]),
                                  $node = this.api().row(row).nodes().to$();

                              if (occp >= 90 ) {
                                 $node.addClass('occupancy_over_90')
                              }
```

This is my function which works well however it adds the class to the entire row, how can i get it to only apply the class to a cell on the 4th column in the row?

Comment: **???** Right in front of you `this.api().row(row).nodes().to$().find('td:eq(4)').addClass()` or use `columns.createdCell()` instead of `rowCallback`.

Comment: Thankyou, however the class disappeared after sorting using this method, didn't try the columns.createdCell()

Comment: No it does not -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/935/**

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, for anyone interested:

```
                           $node = this.api().cells(row, 4).nodes().flatten().to$()
```